# Quantum mechanics problem - superposition principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, superposition

How can one use the solution of the form $\phi^-(x)$ ? I think that the condition $\langle \hat{H} \rangle = \frac{5\hbar^2\pi^2}{2mL^2}$ is only respected with the positive $\phi(x)$

Thank you ! :)

[image: This is my QM problem]

Answer (score 1):

In general, the outcomes of any observable (like momentum) are the eigenvalues of said observable. Now, the actual set of outcomes depends on what state the system is prepared in, so you have to find the eigenvalues for the momentum operator taking into account that the system is in the state $\psi(x,0)$.